# Google Shopping isn't showing products even though there are no errors in the merchant console

Tags: google

I'm having a real frustrating problem with Google Shopping.  We're set up so that it populates our catalog via web scraping, which is all fine and good (the JSON+LD and Schema stuff all works just fine and all the information submitted is as accurate as we have).

However, on a lot of listings, we just aren't showing up even though our prices are competitive and the merchant center doesn't specify any kind of errors.  Other listings show up just fine.

- Are there any other factors I should be looking into to improve performance with the service?
- Should I just dump the web crawler feed and start uploading a generated file every day to keep the listings fresh?

Please help lower my blood pressure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.